# how to show timepicker fragment inside another fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I've created a custom timepicker fragment by extending dialog fragment. but when I call it from the home fragment the app crashes saying : `MainActivity cannot be cast to android.app.TimePickerDialog$OnTimeSetListener`

here's my custom timePickerFragment

```
public class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment{
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), R.style.TimePickerTheme,(TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener) getActivity(),hour,minute,DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
    }
}
```

here's from where I'm calling this fragment:

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment implements AlarmRecyclerViewListener,TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener{
.
.
.

@Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home,container,false);
    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        .
        .
        .
        FloatingActionButton btn = getView().findViewById(R.id.fab_button2);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                DialogFragment timePicker = new TimePickerFragment();
                timePicker.show(getChildFragmentManager(),"time picker");
            }
        });
        @Override
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int hour, int minute) {
            Log.d("msgg","I'm here");
            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
            c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
            c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
          mAlarmsDBhelperClass.insertAlarm("","⚡","",hour,minute,"ON",0,db);
        startAlarm(c,0,true,hour+minute+1);
       }

}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is here

```
return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), R.style.TimePickerTheme,(TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener) getActivity(),hour,minute,DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
```

you already was implementing TimePickerDialog.OnTimerSetListener in HomeFragment, but in this code you tried to get your listener from parent activity.

I think you should inject your listener object to TimerPickerFragment like below code:

```
public class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment {
    //Fragments need to empty constructor
    TimePickerFragment(){

    }

    TimePickerFragment(TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener onTimeSetListener){
        this.onTimeSetListener = onTimeSetListener;
    }
    TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener onTimeSetListener;

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), R.style.TimePickerTheme,onTimeSetListener,hour,minute, DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
    }
}
```

And in HomeFragment you can create TimePickerFragment instance like below:

```
DialogFragment timePicker = new TimePickerFragment(this);
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to pass onTimeSetListener to the TimePickerDialog(). Answer edited

Comment: the time picker dialog appears but I'm unable to retrieve the value from the time picker dialog, in short the onTimeSet() is not being called.

Comment: Did you pass TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener to TimePickerFragment in HomeFragment? maybe it was null.
you should pass it like below within HomeFragment.
DialogFragment timePicker = new TimePickerFragment(this);

Comment: if it was not null, According to the document:
onTimeSet Called when the user is done setting a new time and the dialog has closed.